# Use Chrome Dev Tools as a library?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is Chrome Dev Tools available only through Chrome extensions? Or is there a way we can use it, for instance, as a library from a JS standalone file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update

[Chrome DevTools Frontend](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-devtools-frontend) is now an NPM package that you can take advantage of. It is based from the new [DevTools sub-repo](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/#) in Blink. So you can easily pull in the DevTools assets and keep then up-dated without much work.

---

### Original post

It depends on what you want exactly. You can dig in and rip out bits of the frontend to use. Like [Betwixt](https://github.com/kdzwinel/betwixt) by Konrad pulls the network panel design out and plugs it up to an OS interceptor. So you can use the network panel you know and love to debug any app on your desktop.

Now, can you *easily* do this kind of stuff. Even keeping it auto-updated? No, not really. It is fairly complicated and you need to be able to handle ripping the stuff out yourself. That being said, if you want a challenge then the code is open to everyone.

Comment: Interesting project is Betwixt. Thanks for the info, but indeed, quite complicated.

Comment: +enrmarc Check out the updated post. DevTools now has an npm package you can use.

Answer (score -1):

## Update

There has been some development resulting in my answer not being correct anymore. [@Garbee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2604748/garbee)'s answer is now the one that's right.

---

I'd say that the first sentence on the [About](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) website is pretty clear:

> ... **built into Google Chrome.**

So *officially*, by Google, it's only for Chrome. It's part of Chrome, not a standalone library. Issues linked to DevTools are part of [Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=Cr%3DPlatform-DevTools&sort=&groupby=&colspec=ID%20M%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Modified%20Stars), where people can contribute.

Comment: I read that. Didn't know that "built into" meant that (need to improve my English :)). Thanks.